# Display large icons in the Windows 7 Start Menu under "All programs"

Tags: windows-7, icons, start-menu

I'm trying to setup my tablet PC as a "tablet ready" computer. One of the annoyances is the small icons within the "All programs" section of the Start Menu.

Under Windows 7, is there a way to tell that section to show large icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be accomplished within Windows.  The Vista Start Menu program (which also works for Windows 7) may be an option for you.  It offers Flexible Zoom for the Start Menu.

http://www.vistastartmenu.com/features.html